# problem with the trasposition symbol '

Tags: spacing, symbols, listings, amsmath, matlab

I'm new to latex and I should do an assignment with some matlab code. I wrote the latex file but when I make it into pdf there's a problem with the symbol ' which is the symbol of trasposition in matlab. Here there are the usepackage that I used( I don't know if they're going to be helpfull):

```
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[numberedautolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
```

The problem is that if I write for example

```
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
n =[10:5:25]' ;
\end{lstlisting}
```

then in the pdf it appears a space between `[10:5:25]`   and `'`   so when I copy again on matlab the code is full of errors (I need to make sure that when my professor will copy the code from pdf to matlab everything will go smoothly).
As I said before, I'm new to latex so I don't know what to do, can someone help me?

Comment: Copying code from pdf is always prone to introduce errors - instead you could attach the code, e.g. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2

Comment: If I complete your code and replace the non-standard `mcode` with `listings`, then the pdf does not have a visible space.  But the space does appear when I copy and paste, so I would go with samcarter's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Option `columns=fullflexible` solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,upquote]
n =[10:5:25]' ;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```